# How to understand the numerical sign problem that forbids Monte-Carlo simulations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, path-integral, lattice-model

My question is about how to understand that fermionic models give negative probabilities and thus forbid standard Monte-Carlo simulations? 
In this article (http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0408370) referenced also in an other SE question, one can find that we Taylor-expand $\mathrm{Tr} \exp(-\beta H)$ and insert complete basis states, then get
\begin{align}
Z &= \mathrm{Tr} \exp(-\beta H) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} \frac{(-\beta)^n}{n!} \langle i_1 | H | i_2 \rangle \langle i_2 | H | i_3 \rangle \ldots \langle i_n | H | i_1 \rangle \\
&= \sum_n \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_n} p(i_1, \ldots, i_n) = \sum_c p(c)
\end{align}
Then the authors claim that because of the Pauli principle we must have p(c) < 0, when along $|i_1\rangle \rightarrow |i_2\rangle \rightarrow \ldots \ldots |i_n\rangle \rightarrow |i_1 \rangle$ two fermions are exchanged. My question is about what will be negative in the above expressions, and how can we understand this? Certainly not any basis will lead to negative weights, so without specifying the basis how can we see that it is negative when there is a fermion exchange?

Is there any other simple explanation why do we must have negative "probabilities" in fermionic systems? (And how is this related to the chemical potential? In this "general" fermionic example, nothing is said about chemical potential, but without chemical potential, MC works, doesn't it?)

Comment: *"referenced also in an other SE question"* Might help to link to that other question.